# Plotting Confidence Intervals in ciplot (Stata)

Tags: plot, graph, stata, confidence-interval

I'm working with `ciplot` graphing module in Stata written by Nick Cox and would like to switch the items in the legend with the y-axis. Specifically, I have about 30 feeling thermometers (scale 0-100 and would like to plot the average feeling thermometer "rating" Democrats and Republicans respectively gave each of the 30 groups. So the 30 groups would be along the y-axis and the CIs would indicate Democrats' and Republicans' average ratings for each of the groups.

This is an example of the code I'm currently using (limited to 3 vars here):

```
ciplot ft_black_2017x1 ft_hisp_2017x1 ft_white_2017, by(demgop) horizontal
```

[image]

Is there a way to switch the graph so that the feeling thermometer groups are on the y-axis and the CI points indicate the Democratic and Republican average rating of the group?

I'm open to using packages other than ciplot, but have found it helpful for this task.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you may need a different data structure with race as one variable and Democrat and Republican ratings as two variables. Or perhaps you just need to omit `horizontal`. I am not clear what your wording implies, as the CI points already differentiate the parties.The help for `ciplot` on SSC  carries this warning: "(note added August 2011)  For fuller flexibility, consider using `statsby` first and then standard graphics commands (Cox 2010)." I guess you decided you didn't want to believe that.

Comment: Thanks Nick! seems like statsby is the approach I should be using here.

Comment: Hi Nick, does statsby only allow using one variable at a time? I have 35 variables (feeling thermometers)

Comment: There is no restriction on the command you specify. But if you want confidence intervals for several variables and several groups, you are likely to need a different data structure and/or a loop over `statsby`.